# Class is not available in this context because it is Friend

Tags: c++, vb.net, managed-c++

I am trying to create an instance of a legacy c++ class in VB.NET.  I have followed the instructions on the following webpage: http://windowsdevcenter.com/pub/a/dotnet/2004/03/29/mcpp_part3.html?page=2

1) Created a Visual C++ project with one file (MFoo.cpp) and the following code:

```
class Foo 
{ public: 
// constructor 
Foo(void) {} 
// destructor 
~Foo(void) {} 
// some method 
void DoSomeFoo(){} }; 

__gc class MFoo 
{ public: Foo * _foo; 
public: 
    // constructor 
    MFoo() { _foo = new Foo();} 
    // destructor 
    ~MFoo() { delete _foo; } 
    // method 
    void ManagedDoSomeFoo() { _foo->DoSomeFoo(); } };
```

2) Built the project in Visual C++ producing a DLL
3) Created a reference to the DLL (created in part 2) in a VB.NET application

I now get an error when I try to create an instance of the C++ object i.e. Dim foo As New MFoo.  The error is: MFoo is not available in this context because it is Friend.

Comment: C++/CLI != Managed C++

Comment: @user1937198,Noted.  I have retagged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare the the class MFoo as public, replace the line `__gc class MFoo` with `public __gc class MFoo`